# All categories selected by default for an entry

Tags: entries, categories

Is it possible to create an entry, and have all the categories added by default ?

Let's say I have a category called 'materials', with values like 'gold', 'silver', 'copper'... They should all be added to the entry by default, with the possibility to remove them afterwards

Is this possible in Craft ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a native way to do this, but you could probably pull it off in a [plugin](http://pluginfactory.io) that utilized the `cp.entries.edit` [template hook](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1407/57) and modified the field data directly (selecting whatever categories you want) before returning it to the template.